# location.href not on top of page

Tags: offset, location-href

I have two pages.
In the first I am having some divs that when you click can relocate you to the second page in specific area. for this I am using:

```
<div class='SPcategIn' onclick="location.href='Capability.html#Capa3';" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

It works good.

However it will relocate to the new page and place the Capa3 div at the top of the page. The problem is that I have a header so by doing so there is interference between the header and the Capa3 div.

I would like to relocate as now, but 50px from top so that there wouldn't be any interference and the header will be clear.

Is that possible?

In my mind it should be something like...

```
<div class='SPcategIn' onclick="location.href='Capability.html#Capa3'; offest().top-50" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

Can someone help?

Many thanks,
Elias

Comment: specify in css; :target { margin-top:50px; }

Comment: I have specified a  top:50px in the css, and it works fine on the page. But when I am calling this page from the first one with the click event (shown above) it will not respect the top:50px; Any ideas?

Comment: <style>:target { margin-top:50px; top:50px; }</style>